# Feature Maps vs Channels in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

What's the difference between feature maps and channels in Convolutional Neural Network.

I understand that number feature maps is determined by number of filters. I'm thinking that both of these terms refer to the same thing.

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both are same. Each channel after the first layer of a CNN is a feature map. Before the first layer of CNN, RGB images have 3 channels (red, green & blue channels).